# How can I replay a header which is sent in request to couch db?

Tags: couchdb, couchapp, couchrest

How can I replay a header which is sent as request to couch db, catch is I want to do it for all documents of data base irrespective of show functions.

So I would send a request to couch db for creating a document as

```
 curl -X POST -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: CURL" --data-binary          @${INPUTFILE}  http://someip:port/db
```

where db is my database name created already in couch db and input file is json file to be sent to couch db which will be stored.

Here the response is always as follows

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: CouchDB/1.5.0 (Erlang OTP/R16B01)
Location: http://someip:port/db/14f49d6e537268402761d873560b1da9^M
ETag: "1-ad9ad86f3ca9b8671cd0fcb9e546971f"
Date: Mon, 10 Mar 2014 19:41:07 GMT^M
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 95
Cache-Control: must-revalidate^M

{"ok":true,"id":"14f49d6e537268402761d873560b1da9","rev":"1-ad9ad86f3ca9b8671cd0fcb9e546971f"}
```

Now I need get an additional header in the response. I know we can easily do this by showfunctions, but the catch there is I have to send post request to a url of that show function similar to as follows

```
http://someip:port/db/_design/mydesigndoc/_show/myshowfunction
```

But I don't want this, I want to know whether it would be possible to just post to `http://someip:port/db/` and get a custom response header back?

Or is there a way where I can front end the address to `http://someip:port/db` and forward it to  `http://someip:port/db/_design/mydesigndoc/_show/myshowfunction` when ever I receive a request? I guess this should be possible, but couldn't figure out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Virtual hosts is not helping much, and behaving weird, any other solution to achieve this?

Comment: Got it working with Update handler and virtual hosts, now the problem is, if I override the headers in response, then default response headers are lost, not sure where to get those from, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the virtual hosts and/or rewriting documentation will help:

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/http.html#virtual-hosts

Comment: I'm already trying on those lines, Thanks for the suggestion anyways. I'll post the solution and mark this as solution if I'm successful.

Comment: Finally update handler along with vhosts setup did the job for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Finally came up with a solution, we suits my use case. Although I lose the headers generated by Couch in response, I'm ok with that for my case.

The update handlers, Rewrite URL, Show function and vhosts combination helped me.

As mentioned in my problem statement, the url I want to hit is

```
http://someip:port/dbname?version=1
```

If I were to have liberty to change this, I would have solved this problem with less effort. But this is the URL that will be hit with a POST request for creating a document in couch DB.

There are two solutions, one create the dbname as different If you can do that, and redirect this URL to the update handler URL in the rewrite or directly using vhosts.

If you cannot change dbname to a different thing, the problem is more complicated, if you put

```
http://someip:port/dbname?version=1
```

in the vhosts and direct it to update handler, then you cannot access the db from Futon UI as get request from Futon UI would direct to update handler and HTTP method mismatch error is thrown.

To overcome this, create a rewrite handler for directing requests coming from

```
someip:port/dbname?version=1
```

to update handler, and requests coming to

```
someip:port/dbname
```

to a show function, which shows the default view as seen from Futon.

Best solution would be, if you have liberty to change DB name then redirect the URL to the DB design doc's update handler for POST.